# PDF file inside webview click not working in few devices

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I need to load a PDF file within my webview on a button click within it. I have used google docs URL for loading the same. It works perfectly in S8 edge(v9.0) but it's not working in S6 edge(v6.0.1). It is not calling the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method even. Not able to understand what is the exact reason for it.

My code:

```
private final String googleDocs = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (request.getUrl().toString().endsWith("pdf")) {
                String pdfUrl = googleDocs + request.getUrl().toString();
                view.loadUrl(pdfUrl);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = binding.webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url); 
}
```